# CoordinatorLayout blank space under toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

When I start my application on a virtual device it is like an ekstra toolbar appears on my activity.
It is an activity with nested scrollview and collapsing toolbar. All the animations and all the buttons works perfectly, but it seems like it adds ekstra space and it is exactly the size of a collapsed/regular toolbar.

If I change the coordinatorLayout layout_height to "wrap_content" the extra space will go to the bottom of the screen instead of being right under the correct toolbar.

Can anyone see what the problem is? I have tried a plethora of different settings now.

[Non collapsed toolbar with imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjd9c.png)
[Collapsed toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcVuO.png)

Heres the code for the activity:

```
public class algorithms_abcde extends AppCompatActivity {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_algorithms_abcde);

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getString(R.string.btn_txt_abcde));
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        //Inflate the menu; This adds it to the actionba
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_other, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Determines which button has been pressed.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        //Switch case to handle item presses on the action bar
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml of the activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".algorithms_abcde"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorVeryLight"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/headLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img_abcde_headline"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollAbleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/stringtest"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Heres the xml of the themes.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorVeryLight</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and and lastly the manifest:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".algorithms_opqrst"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".algorithms_abcde" />
        <activity android:name=".algorithms_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try removing android:layout_gravity="bottom" from CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Sadly that did not work. Actually it didn't do anything at all to the activity

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
I had to remove all the "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" and add it to the CoordinatorLayout. 
Then I also had to remove the "android:layout_gravity="bottom"" from both the CoordinatorLayout and the NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

We must remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from CoordinatorLayout

and apply this code in fragment or activity

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    activity?.let {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it.window, false)
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(viewBinding.root) { _, insets ->
                val imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
                viewBinding.root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight)
                insets
            }
        } else {
            it.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        }
    }
}
```